# Mapping Network Drive Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, network-drive, directory-tree

I'm new to node and I'm trying to get a list of files in a network drive using the directory-tree plugin but I'm getting a null return. Has anyone had this problem

```
var dirTree = require('directory-tree');

var tree = dirTree('\\\\10.10.1.6\\Images');
console.log(tree);
```

Comment: Do the Node.js built-in filesystem methods work on Windows network paths?

Comment: @Brad yes, we can access network path files via "fs" but not sure about this library

Comment: @binariedMe I thought it only worked for local drives, would i just use the readdir method?

Comment: I really think you should if other library don't work

Answer (score 0):

There can be another way to find the contents in the directory which is using smb2 module.
As network drive requires user credentials to access its contents therefore it is returning null. Also if we try to access it using file system of Node js then it may also return access denied. 
So to access the contents of network location we can use external node library i.e [SMB2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/smb2)

An example for the same can be -

```
var smb2 = require('smb2');
var epConfig = {
smb2PdfGenerateConfig: {
    share: '\\\\10.10.1.6'
    , domain: 'domain'
    , username: 'username'
    , debug: false
    , password: 'password!'
    , autoCloseTimeout: 0
 }
}
var smb2Client = new smb2({
    share: epConfig.smb2PdfGenerateConfig.share,
    domain: epConfig.smb2PdfGenerateConfig.domain,
    username: epConfig.smb2PdfGenerateConfig.username,
    password: epConfig.smb2PdfGenerateConfig.password,
    debug: epConfig.smb2PdfGenerateConfig.debug,
    autoCloseTimeout: epConfig.smb2PdfGenerateConfig.autoCloseTimeout
});

smb2Client.readdir('Images', function(err, files){
    if(err) console.log("err",err);
    else{
       for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
            console.log("file",files[i]);
       }
    }
});
```